# Found uknown characters and special characters in url in ap.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting some special characters and some letters along with the url at runtime. The url is like
 http://b1.elenageosystems.com/%28S%28z1qmpcpllhmuoxgsnkhcbflh%29%29/Default.aspx

Here you can see the special characters appended along with the url after b1.elenageosystems.com/.....

Default.aspx is my page

You can view my project - www.b1.elenageosystems.com

Comment: Where's the question?

Answer (score 0):

This is so-called `Session ID` that used by `IIS` to manage your sessions, it is added to every URL firing from the same browser session.

Many IIS-based frameworks (for example classical ASP.NET) depend heavily on sessions and require this ID to overcome generale stateless nature of HTTP requests, this is why IIS provides (and implements) fully transparent support for it.

If you don't like these URLs, you can also use Cookies to store your `Session ID`. You can configure the way how you store your IDs for sessions either per `WebApplication` using your `web.config` file in your application or globally for your complete IIS server.

You find more how to change these settings [on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730858%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).